# ¿Cómo remover indicaciones al trazar una ruta en la API de Google Maps?

Tags: google-api

Quiero ocultar las indicaciones como en la siguiente imagen:

[image: indicaciones]

El código siguiente es donde asigno las opciones introducir el código aquí a la hora de pintar la ruta:

```
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({ 
    preserveViewport : true, 
    suppressMarkers: true, 
    hideRouteList : false,
    suppressInfoWindows : true,
    suppressBicyclingLayer : true,
    preserveViewport : true
});
directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService({
    provideRouteAlternatives : false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Estaba haciendo pruebas y la solución fue la siguiente: en el jsp tuve que crear un `div`:

```
<div id="indicacionesMaps" style="display: none;"></div>
```

Y en la clase instanciada de `directionsDisplay` llame al método `setPanel` de la siguiente forma:

```
directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('indicacionesMaps'));
```

Por ende cuando trace la ruta las indicaciones se insertaran en el `div` que acabo de crear, y como el `div` esta oculto no se mostraran las indicaciones.